# Spotify constantly "Loading"

Tags: windows-10-mobile, music, lumia-950-xl

I have, reluctantly, moved from Groove Music Pass (which I've been using since it was Zune Pass) to Spotify Premium. However, the app on W10M seems to be *very* unreliable. I'm looking for advice on making it, frankly, suck less.

Spotify app will occasionally fail to launch with an error something like "Could not start music playback". My best guess is that this is related to the thing where W10M only allows one app to play music at a time, although that's still weird since no other app is doing so when this happens. This error sometimes goes away after a few launch attempts and always (so far) goes away after restarting the phone if I launch the app first thing afterward (though I don't like doing that so often).

The **BIG** problem is that the vast majority of the times I launch the app, it greys the screen with a "Loading..." animation for about 3 of every 6 seconds. While doing this, the app is unusable. You can't interact with it at all while the Loading animation is happening, but even the rest of the time, it doesn't actually work right. You can search for music, but it won't show your collection or followed artists correctly and you can't add more. It won't play any sound at all under any circumstance - it won't even switch to a "Now Playing" view, in fact - when it's doing this, which of course makes it worthless as a music app. This problem happens way too often, and when it happens, it doesn't seem to *stop* happening until rebooting, or even reinstalling the whole app, and sometimes not then. Sometimes after rebooting the phone it doesn't exhibit this problem for a while, but then it starts again.

I tried using the web-based player, at open.spotify.com, which *should* work - Edge supports DRM media streams, and the website itself is reasonably touch-friendly - but it's one of those  websites that uses extremely aggressive user-agent sniffing and forces you to use the mobile site, which does nothing except tell you to use the non-functional app. (Even though my browser is set to the desktop user agent string, the server gives you the worthless mobile page if it detects the string "Lumia XXX" where "X" is any number.) I could fix this if I could edit the user-agent string, but all the apps I can find which support that use the legacy IE (i.e. WP8.x or even WP7.x) rendering engine and don't support web modern standards. Alternatively, if there was a URL or something I could use to force the page into desktop mode, that would be OK.

---

So, my actual request: I'd like a way to make Spotify work on the phone, at least until my subscription is up and I can move to something better. The options I can see, that I will accept recommendations for, are:

1. A way to make the app behave itself and actually work, oh, at least 50% of the time. I'd settle for 25% at this point, even.
2. A way to load the web-based player on the phone without being redirected to a garbage mobile site, in a browser that can use said desktop-mode web player.
3. Some alternative way (third-party app?) to get Spotify working on W10M.

Any help would be very appreciated!